# Access Router Params VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I'm creating a blog using Vuejs and I'm fairly new to it.

In short. I have a dynamic list of elements that are loaded onto the screen and when you click on one of the items, I want to go to that page with the rest of the data. I followed somewhat of the same process I did if I was using React.

**Router.js**

```
export default new Router({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/post/:id",
      name: "PostView",
      props: true,
      component: PostView
    }
  ]
});
```

I have my router setup to take dynamic links.

**Component That Creates List Data**

```
<template>
  <router-link v-bind:to="{ path: 'post/' + post.postId, params: { post } }">
    <div> .... </div>
  </router-link>
</template>

<script>
import moment from "moment";

export default {
  name: "recentPostTile",
  props: {
    post: Object,
  },
};
</script>
```

As you can see that is how I did my router-link and in my actual Page View this is how I'm trying to read the data. 2 different way's I tried to read it.

```
  props: {
    post: Object
  },

AND

  data() {
    return {
      postData: this.$route.params.post, (also tried with $route)
    };
  },
```

and when I try to console out post/postData I just get undefined. I can assure you that the data does exist since the data is hard coded into the browser.

Also I tried to pass the params as key value pairs as well and that didn't work. I also create a new variable for the data I was going to be passing through the link. That didn't work either. I also haven't tired query, just because I don't want an ugly looking link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your link to:

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'PostView', params: { id: post.postId, postData: post } }">
   <div> .... </div>
</router-link>
```

The changes:

- Used the `name` property to specify the route
- Removed the hardcoded path
- Passed the `id` param, as that is the param name given in the route definition (`/:id`)

Comment: Why specifying the route with <path> property not works??

Comment: @Babaktrad It does work if you put the id directly in the path, but with complex params it's cleaner to use the `params` object. You can do whichever you prefer.